# Globally Deserialize with underscore/hyphen/case insensitivity in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

For a property, `anyCase`, looking to be able to get a Jackson (2.7.x) ObjectMapper to recognize that `any_case`, `any-case`, `ANYCASE`, `AnYcAsE` are equivalent for purposes of deserialization without needing to use annotations on individual classes.

I recognize that the following is possible:

`mapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);`

However, this method does not work for underscores and hyphens.